# Getting formatexception

Tags: c#

I am getting a Formatexception from the below code. I can't seem to fix it. What is wrong? Thanks

```
var res = dropDown.SelectedValue;
var zip = String.Format("{0}/FileBrowser/FOLDERNAME/filer/" + temp + ", projectPath");
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to `{0}` in the format string

```
"{0}/FileBrowser/FOLDERNAME/filer/" + temp + ", projectPath"
```

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects an argument after it.

Did you mean something like

```
var zip = String.Format("{0}/FileBrowser/FOLDERNAME/filer/{1}", projectPath, temp);
```